Verifying the checksum of a file the easier way?
I want to know if there's a checksum verification tool that compares files of my choice(one or more) by right clicking on it in the Windows Explorer and the context menu shows item such as "verify this file" and it compares the hash checksum(such as MD5) with the original source already saved as *.md5 file that has list of files with hash values. It would be better if the same tool creates the initial checksum file that lists hash value of the files that I want.
There're some tools out there that calculates the checksum of the selected files but nowhere can I find the tool that supports verification via context menu as well.
Any thoughts or recommendations?

Which tools have you tried that don't satisfy you? Why? BTW, MD5 is a really bad choice for a checksum nowadays. It can be attacked.

HashCheck does what you want:
Verifying a file

Download a file
Download the checksum file, e.g. a .SHA256 file
Double click the checksum file in order to check the downloaded file (from step 1)

Here's how that looks like for a Linux Mint distribution. It has attempted to check all the files, but could only find one of them, because I downloaded only one and not the other two:

Creating checksums for a new file
The other direction is as simple:

right click a file (open the context menu in Explorer)
choose "Create Checksum file..."
Choose the type of the checksum



